# add break to HTML variable text

Tags: php, tcpdf

I am using a php library (tcpdf) and am trying to create a header that has multipel lines.

my syntax is:

```
$customerhead="line1 /n line2 /n line3";
define ('PDF_HEADER_STRING2', "Report Ran: ".$customerhead);
```

this renders the following pdf syntax:

```
 line1 /n line2 /n line3
```

this is all on one line and the /n is ignored.

I did try with '' but this too is ingored?

```
line1 <br> line2 <br> line3
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about you use this function `nl2br()`.

```
<?php
    echo nl2br("foo isn't\n bar");
?>
```

[DOCS](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.nl2br.php)

So you'd have

```
$customerhead = nl2br("line1 \n line2 \n line3");
define ('PDF_HEADER_STRING2', "Report Ran: ".$customerhead);
```

Or if not, if it did not accept/work.

```
$customerhead = "line1 \n line2 \n line3";
define ('PDF_HEADER_STRING2', "Report Ran: ".$customerhead);
```

Then use `nl2br()` when you use `PDF_HEADER_STRING2` them later.

```
echo nl2b(PDF_HEADER_STRING2);
// or
$var = nl2b(PDF_HEADER_STRING2);
```

Also, I noticed you used `/n`, what I know you declare new line via `\n`

Comment: Thanks so much. great stuff. second options works great.  option one shows the <br>